# HTML file:// links : open in explorer from Chrome

Tags: html, file, google-chrome, explorer

I have an html file with links like that :

```
<a href="N:\folder1\folder2">folder name</a>
```

I would like that this link opens explorer instead of a custome chrome file html based browser. This works from IE btw.

Thank you !
Nicolas.

Comment: It can't be done on Chrome, Opera or Safari.

Comment: I would recommend this [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/local-explorer-file-manag/eokekhgpaakbkfkmjjcbffibkencdfkl). It allows you to open folder & files directly on Chrome. Quite convenient to use. However, it requires you to install a file called "Integration Module". Honestly not a fan of this practice. But at least there is no suspicious thing in this file as far as I checked.

Comment: @BradsonErik I had kind of thought an external process would be needed to open the default file manager, but this particular extension seems shady. It just provides a link to the EXE with no source code, and VirusTotal says two viruses are found, and the home page says coming soon or something. Isn't there any more trust-able extension than that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For `Chrome`, `Safari` and `Opera` this **isn't possible** due to their security model. However, there is somewhat of a solution for `Chrome` in that it's possible but it has two requirements:

1. You need to get the user to install [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-local-file-links/nikfmfgobenbhmocjaaboihbeocackld?hl=en)
2. It must be over `https://`

You will probably encounter the same problem for `Firefox` since it usually requires `LocalLink`.

***[Further reading](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/12/security-in-depth-local-web-pages.html)***

Comment: Thank you for you answer. For your point 2, file:// for a local directory wont work ?

Comment: Chrome extension works for http internally web project

Comment: Don't bother. That extension is for opening a local file, not a local directory with the default file manager like Windows File Explorer. Why, the very name of the extension is "Enable local FILE links".