# Launch Windows Explorer from web application in browser

Tags: windows, google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser, web

I’m building a PHP web application that runs only using Google Chrome. The organization would like to be able to access certain folders via windows explorer. This is easy in IE using the file:/// protocol but I can’t seem to find a good solution using Chrome.

I’ve looked into registering custom protocol handlers but haven’t really found the answer I’m looking for there. This requirement is grained in stone; they do not want to access the files via web browser.

Does anyone know if there’s a way to launch windows explorer from google chrome either through a special protocol handler or by temporarily launching IE to get the file path to open? A simple method or example would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Chrome does provide a folder listing. Do you specifically need it to be in Windows Explorer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML file:// links : open in explorer from Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446357/html-file-links-open-in-explorer-from-chrome)

Comment: Unfortunately it does need to be windows explorer. @castis I did read that link however I don't think that's the solution I'm going for. Chrome now supports custom protocol handlers but I'm just not sure how to get it to work for this case. Also I could go about it a hacky way by having the application trigger a new IE window to open launch windows explorer and shut down again, just not sure how to do that.

Comment: I understand. The web browser doesn't help, here. A way to describe the problem is: you want to run a command (explorer) at the request of the _server_. I'm thinking: you ask the user to install a tool (maybe made with python, for simplicity?) that stays in the system tray and listens for (https?) requests coming **from your server**. You check the request and eventually craft and run the windows system command that launches the file explorer. Obviously, if it is made bad, it could be abused by malwares. I know it's an ugly solution. What do you think?

Comment: I've just found this:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/local-explorer-file-manag/eokekhgpaakbkfkmjjcbffibkencdfkl
It may help... But I don't understand how does it launch external applications.

Comment: Thanks @MatteoT. -- this is somewhat useful the main problem is that it does not allow users to update or modify a file. It seems to be a more on the lines of a formatted view of the directory. Right now IE Tab is working it allows the user to open/modify/rename the file like in Windows Explorer. I'm appending the chrome extension ID to the link that opens the page: chrome-extension://hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd/nhc.htm#url=myURL which works but chrome does not allow this window to be opened on its own. The user must manually right click / open new tab which is a pain.